# WP admin panel is broken and no links worked

Tags: wordpress

WP Admin panel is broken, no link works, and only some links are visible.
I tried full permission on the directory level, and disable all themes and plugins.

Comment: check you index.php and hope you will see some unwanted code there

Comment: Share screen shot for error

Answer (score 0):

Login via FTP or CPanel and in the wp-config.php before require_once add below code into file :

```
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);
```

From the official docs:

> To result in faster administration screens, all JavaScript files are
> concatenated into one URL. If JavaScript is failing to work in an
> administration screen, you can try disabling this feature.

https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/wp-config-php/#disable-javascript-concatenation

Answer (score 0):

please check wp-config.php and edit it according to your database.
Also Check wp_options in my sql data base

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in .htaccess file in WordPress root directory. If not exits the file please create it.

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

Still, if it not works please add the two lines of code in the wp-config.php file

```
 define('WP_HOME','http://yourdomain.com');
 define('WP_SITEURL','http://yourdomain.com');
```

Thank you